# How to change the text of a textlabel in a game scene

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to change the text of a basic text label which I added within a game scene. 
But I do not know how to do this by code.
For now I assigned a name to the label in scene editor but I do not know how to continue from here and a sign an new text value to the label.

Currently I use

```
    let scoreLabel = childNodeWithName("scoreLabel") as! SKLabelNode
```

But I receive an error message "Use of instance member 'childNodeWithName' on type 'SKNode'; did you mean to use a value of type 'SKNode' instead?
But since I want to make use of functionalities of a text labe, the SKNode Class is not sufficient for me.

Anyone who got some help?

Comment: If you want more info about that error, please provide more context about where this code is placed (eg. is it a property of a scene / some other class, which would be wrong, or it is defined locally in some method etc).

Comment: @Whirlwind Basically I just place the line within the GameScene Class, where I also put my other variables and definitions. But I am searching for an opportunity to do something like: scoreLabel.text = "3"

Comment: I put the setup of the timer in a separate function and called it on "didMove", Solved the problem :) Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of how to set a SKLabelNode either as a property and locally, and access those variables later in your code:

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    let label = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "ArialMT")

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        label.text = "This is a label defined as a property of scene";
        label.fontSize = 35;
        label.fontColor = .blackColor()
        label.position = CGPoint(x:frame.midX, y:frame.midY)

        addChild(label)

        let anotherLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "ArialMT")
        anotherLabel.text = "This is a label defined localy and added to a node tree"
        anotherLabel.name = "anotherLabel"
        anotherLabel.fontSize = 35;
        anotherLabel.fontColor = .whiteColor()
        anotherLabel.position = CGPoint(x:frame.midX, y:frame.midY - 100.0)

        addChild(anotherLabel)

    }


    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {


        self.label.text = "Your text"

        if let anotherLabel = childNodeWithName("anotherLabel") as? SKLabelNode {

            anotherLabel.text = "Your text"
        }
    }
}
```

In the case of a property, accessing is simple as `self.label.text = "..."`. In the case of a local variable, added to a node tree, you use its name property to find it later using `childNodeWithName` method.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work for the original poster, but as of 2020, the correct syntax to add a node created in the scene builder to the program is something like that

```
var mySkNode = childNode(withName:"//nameOfNode") as? SKNode;
```

If it is a SKLabelNode, you should replace SKNode with SKLabelNode, and same for every specific SpriteKit class.